# is it possible to add Google recaptcha v2(Checkbox I'm not robot) in contact form 7

Tags: recaptcha, contact-form-7

I have created a contact form 7 application form. I want to add Google recaptcha v2. I don't want v3 of Google recaptcha.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>First Name</label> [text* first-name id:speci minlength:3 maxlength:20]
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>Last Name</label> [text* last-name id:speci minlength:3 maxlength:20]
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>Email</label> [email* email maxlength:30]
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>Phone</label> [tel* tel minlength:8 maxlength:20]
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>Description</label> [textarea* Description]
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  </div>

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="cvvdfvvdsvkjgjksdncscs"></div>
  [submit id:contact-submit "Send"]
</div>
```

that's a dummy site key

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the contact form 7 integration method. If you haven't done that already:**

1. Go to Google’s [reCAPTCHA admin page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).
2. Register your site.
3. Get a **site key** and **secret key**.

> Choose the **reCAPTCHA v2** + **Checkbox** type.

[image]

**Copy the key pair into the WordPress admin screen of the site you registered.**

- Go to the admin menu **Contact** > **Integration**.
- Find reCAPTCHA panel and click Configure Keys.
- Copy the **site key** and **secret key** into the fields and save them.

[image]

**Finally instead of using**

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="cvvdfvvdsvkjgjksdncscs"></div>
```

**Just use:**

`[recaptcha size:compact]`

---

Check source [here](https://contactform7.com/recaptcha-v2/)